# Docker Mount Project error response from daemon on Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, virtualbox, docker-for-windows

I am new in using Docker and I want to mount my project in a container to run it on a Virtual Host. First of all I installed the Docker Toolbox that works for Windows 10. I am using the Docker QuickStart Terminal as my CLI to work with. I tried to pull an image that I will use for my project and it was successfull.

Unfortunately when I try to mount my project I get this error.

> C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from
>   daemon: invalid mode: /var/www/app/. See 'C:\Program Files\Docker
>   Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.

And this is the command to mount the project on that specific image to create a container that I will run on.

```
docker run -d --name=cbpass_container -v C:\Users\me\Documents\cbpass\server:/var/www/app/ -P -p 5432:5432 -t -i
image/someimagename:dev
```

Is there any problem with my command?
Appreciate if someone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Could you figure out what the problem was?

Comment: @Georgy didn't seem to find a solution. :( I shifted to ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

try changing host path to : `/C/Users/public/xxx`

I test with OK with the following cmd (**Windows 7**):

```
docker run -p xxx:xxx --network=host -it -v /c/Users/Public/log:/var/log --rm --privileged registry.xxxxxx.xxxx.xxx
```

May this help you :)

Comment: I used /c/docker:/data, and it is ok running. I see /data folder as well, but I think /c/docker is not correctly mapping as /data folder is empty or /c/docker is meant something else. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the [shared drives](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/06/14/configuring-docker-for-windows-volumes/)?

Comment: how do I do that? Is there a settings for the VM or Docker?

Comment: OP is using docker toolbox by the way, that link describes docker for windows steps.

Answer (score 0):

In docker for windows, you have options/settings to add a directory for sharing. I think that handles what I am going to describe.

In docker toolbox, we have VirtualBox running between our own machine and container. So when you are going to share a folder, you have to share it with Virtual Machine first, then you can share with container.

In VirtualBox, find your docker-machine (probably default), then in settings you can find Shared Folders. After adding your folder there, please pick a wise name for your folder.
Then you will see that when you ssh your container in toolbox, you will see there is a folder in path "/your-folder-name". 
You can then use -v argument with that path.