# win7 docker mount always error: C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid mode:/opt/webapp

Tags: docker, windows-7

[image]

$ docker run -d -v d:/dockerfile:/opt/webapp 6fae60ef3446

C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /opt/webapp.

why always show the error, how to be ok? please!

Comment: Facing the same on Win10, here is a similar question, no answer there though. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091139/docker-mount-project-error-response-from-daemon-on-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that Docker Toolbox needs a different approach as stated in this discussion

[Docker Forums: Map Windows Directory to Docker Container](https://forums.docker.com/t/map-windows-directory-to-docker-container/5715)

As they said,

> On Windows, you can not directly map Windows directory to your container. Because your containers are reside inside a VirtualBox VM. So your docker -v command actually maps the directory between the VM and the container.
>
> So you have to do it in two steps:
>
> Map a Windows directory to the VM through VirtualBox manager
> Map a directory in your container to the directory in your VM
> You better use the Kitematic UI to help you. It is much eaiser.

- I first defined a shared folder on VirtualBox to the machine I use.
- Then closed that machine and docker windows, then started docker toolbox again.
- Then run docker-machine ssh default, and just change directory to the folder you shared (with given name). Mine was "cd mydocker", then with ls you can see the files you shared with VM.
- And in toolbox, run docker run -it -v /mydocker:/path_in_container image_name /bin/sh
- You should see the folder and content in /path_in_container.